# SAR Circuit in Analog to Digital Converter

Tags: digital-logic, analog

[image: Successive Approximation ADC]

Hi, I have been trying to figure out which circuit is inside the SAR block. I've looking in the internet but I haven't found anything yet. Does any one know how the circuit inside the SAR looks like?

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially a sort of parallel-set / serial-in / parallel-out shift register with a twist.

It starts with 1000 (assuming four bits). When the comparator deems this value too low, a 1 is shifted in at the high side, when it is deemed too high, a 0 is shifted in. In both cases 1 bit of the result (the MSB) has been determined.

Now the value is x100, and the cycle is repeated three more times to determine the next 3 bits, but those bits are shifted in at positions 2, 1 and 0 instead of at the highest bit.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://lsm.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lsm/files/shared/Reports/Ferrara_MasterThesis_2012.pdf) an explanation of an example of the SAR register circuit in page 46.

Answer (score 0):

It's better visualized as an algorithm than a circuit (though it's implemented as a bunch of digital logic). What it does is exactly equivalent to a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).